# Apache IOUtils.copyLarge

Tags: java, android, apache-commons

I am downloading files using Apache IOUtils. For resuming the download I am using the following code:

```
IOUtils.copyLarge(input,output,localFileSize,fileLengthOnServer - localFileSize);
```

The problem is when clicking the resume button the download does not resume, but starts from beginning as I guess, because as I see there is no progress on file size for some time (based on the size already downloaded).

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't know you're reading from an HTTP server. All is has is an input stream, and all it can do with that is skip to the offset you specify. If you want the *server* to do that you need to look at setting the HTTP `Range:` header yourself.

Comment: if I read the file manually I can set setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + localFileSize + "-"); but dont know how to do this with Apache Commons!

Comment: You *can't* do this with Apache Commons. Apache Commons is speaking `InputStream`, not HTTP. You have to do it yourself. Which is exactly what my answer already says.